# Can we deserialize the StyleDocument object in java?

Tags: java, swing

Actually I serialize the object of the `StyleDocument` class in my program and saved it in a file, and when I deserialize the `StyleDocument` class object it throws `StreamCorruptedException`.

`File file = new File("D:/styleDocument.zmp");`

Serialization code :

```
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    //area is JTextPane
    oos.writeObject(area.getStyledDocument());
    oos.close();
```

Deserialization code:

```
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) ois.readObject();
    area.setStyledDocument(doc);
    ois.close();
```

So how can I deserialize the `StyleDocument` object?

Exception Log :

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00496173
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at swing.Notepad.openFile(Notepad.java:299)
at swing.Notepad.actionPerformed(Notepad.java:215)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

[This is the Serialize file mm.zmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRVyv.png)

Comment: Can you provide full exception from logs?

Comment: Have you tried not using nested streams but to use try-with-resources? Maybe there's an issue with the closing of the nested streams:
`try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);)` (same for input too)

Comment: @Christian I have use your technique but it throw `java.io.NotSerializableException` . But when I am not use your code it serialize the `StyledDocument` object.

Comment: @Christian And also how can I serialize the `StyledDocument` class

Comment: @Christian How can I implement `Serializable` interface in `StyledDocument`. Can we do this with Reflection API or not or How we do this ?